# time picker ontimeset is wrong

Tags: java, android, time, timepicker

i have a date and time picker in my app and I've just noticed that the time is wrong. the current time that the time picker displays is i hour delay and its am/pm is wrong like for example the current time is `2:55 pm` it will show `1:55 am` what seems to be the problem here is the code

UPDATE:DATE AND TIME PICKER

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnCalendar) {

        // Process to get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DATE)+1;

        // Launch Date Picker Dialog
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // Display Selected date in textbox
                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.show();
    }
    if (v == btnTimePicker) {

        // Process to get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+1;
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                            int minute) {
                        // Display Selected time in textbox
                        txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        tpd.show();
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE:
what i did is to put +1 in `mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+1;` there might be a set back on this method any ideas?

unfixed is the AM/PM button is wrong it always shows am at start

UPDATE:AM/PM doesn't start with am at all is wrong because now that its morning it show pm but during pm it show am

UPDATE:
there is also a problem in date.what i did is to put +1 in `mDay = c.get(Calendar.DATE)+1;` there might be a set back on this method any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Its a bug. It has been reported to google. You can find it here
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24388
and 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18982

Comment: I thought i'm doing something wrong thank you saved me alot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp" />

TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int Hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
                int Minute = tp.getCurrentMinute();

                    txtTime.setText(String.valueOf(Hour) + ":" + String.valueOf(Minute));

            }
        });
```

Comment: i tried it but it is still 1 hour delay and the am/pm is wrong as well as the tutorials above..

Comment: Buddy its difinitely working. Its the source code from my project.

Comment: Buddy can you put the entire thing maybe i have put something wrong wrong..when i click i still get a time that is 1 hour late and the AM/PM is wrong

Comment: Just make a new demo project and Put my code in it. Then compare it.

Comment: just tried it but still it has a delay of 1 hour like the time now is 10:07 but its showing 9:07

Comment: Then you have an unwanted option i.e to increase the time hour by 1 until you find some universal solution.

Comment: yeah i think there will be a set back on this which i havent encountered yet...thats why i posted the solution maybe there are issues that can be solve here but i cant make you code run sorry